# Cant Get Gui To Appear When I run Program

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, user-interface, jframe

need some help here im working on a project and ive only started using eclipse and i cant get the gui to pop up on the screen when i run the program i just want to see how its looking so far does anyone thing the have the answer ill show the code below all help appreciated its divided into 3 classes also and some of the methods arent finished but there all called and created so theres no errors it says
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Car {
String carReg ="";  
String make;
String model;
String price;

public Car(String carReg, String make, String model, String price) 
{
    this.carReg=carReg;
    this.make=make;
    this.model=model;
    this.price=price;
}
/*
 getters and setters
 */
public String getcarReg() {
    return carReg;
}
public void setcarReg(String reg) {
    carReg=reg;
}
public String getprice() {
    return price;
}
public void setprice(String pri) {
    price=pri;
}
public String getmodel() {
    return model;
}
public void setmodel(String mod) {
    model=mod;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}
public void setMake(String mk) {
    make=mk;
}

}
/////////////////////////////////////

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Menu {

    GarageManager gm = new GarageManager();
    private static Icon myIcon = new ImageIcon("..\\CarGarage\\src\\ie.wit.CarGarage\\cargarage.jpg");

    public Menu() {

        String option = "";

        do {
            JLabel addl = new JLabel("1.Add A Car To Stock");
             JLabel removel = new JLabel("2.Remove a Car From Stock");
             JLabel viewl = new JLabel("3.View All Car's In Stock");
             JLabel updatel = new JLabel("4.Update A Car In Stock");
             JLabel exitl = new JLabel("5.Exit System");
             JTextField userChoiceTextField = new JTextField();
             Object [] MainMenu = new Object[7];
                     MainMenu[0]= myIcon;
                     MainMenu[1]= addl; 
                     MainMenu[2]= removel;
                     MainMenu[3]= viewl;
                     MainMenu[4]= updatel;
                     MainMenu[5]= exitl;
                     MainMenu[6]= userChoiceTextField;

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, MainMenu);
                     option = userChoiceTextField.getText();




                     switch(option)
                        {
                        case "1":
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            break;
                            default: break;
                        }

if(option =="1");
{
    JLabel carRegl = new JLabel("Please Enter Car Registration");
    JLabel makel = new JLabel("Please Enter Car Make");
    JLabel modell = new JLabel("Please Enter Car Model");
    JLabel pricel = new JLabel("Please Enter Car Price");
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    JTextField JcarReg= new JTextField();
    JTextField Jmake= new JTextField();
    JTextField Jmodel= new JTextField();
    JTextField Jprice= new JTextField();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Object [] addCarA = new Object[9];
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    addCarA[0] = myIcon;
    addCarA[1] = carRegl;
    addCarA[2] = JcarReg;
    addCarA[3] = makel;
    addCarA[4] = Jmake;
    addCarA[5] = modell;
    addCarA[6] = Jmodel;
    addCarA[7] = pricel;
    addCarA[8] = Jprice;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  addCarA);
    String carReg1 = JcarReg.getText();
    String make1 = Jmake.getText();
    String model1 = Jmodel.getText();
    String price1 = Jprice.getText();

    String allCars="Car Registration: "+carReg1+ "\n Make:"+make1+ "\n Model:"+model1+ "\n Price:"+price1;
    Car carNew = new Car(carReg1, make1, model1, price1);

    boolean carTest = gm.addCar(carNew);
    if ( carTest==true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  allCars);
    }
    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car Wasnt Added to System");
    }
}
if(option =="2");
{
    String reg1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Car Registration to Remove:");
    boolean test = gm.removes(reg1);
    if(test == true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car Has Been Removed");
    }
    else if(test == false) 
    {

    }
}
if(option =="3");
{

    String printAllCars = gm.view();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printAllCars);
}
if(option =="4");
{
    String reg1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Car Registration");
    boolean carUpdate = gm.update();
    if (carUpdate == true)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car Has Been Updated");
    }
    else if(carUpdate == false)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Car With Registation" + reg1 + "Does Not Exist In The System");

    }
}
if(option =="5");
{
    System.exit(0);

}
        }while(option !="5");


    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

    }







}
///////////////////////////////////////////
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class GarageManager {

    private static Icon myIcon = new ImageIcon("..\\CarGarage\\src\\ie.wit.CarGarage\\cargarage.jpg");



    List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public boolean addCar(Car newCar) 
    {
        boolean carTest = false;
        carList.add(newCar);
        carTest = true;
        return carTest;

    }

    public boolean removes(String reg)
    {
        boolean carRemove = false;
        return carRemove;
    }

    public String view()
    {
        String carDetails = "";
        return carDetails;
    }
    public boolean update()
    {
        boolean car1 = true;
        return car1;
    }

    public boolean shutdown()
    {
        boolean car = true;
        return car;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a main method?

Comment: as in a public string args? im not a great programmer so excuse my answers if the seem dumb

Comment: Yeah. Thats the code that gets run automatically on run.

Comment: i have one in on the Menu at the very bottom has nothing in it tho

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you never actually instantiate your GUI. You have all of the code there but it never gets executed because you do not have anything in your main method.

In JAVA the main method is the most important method as it is the starting point of reference for all subsequent code. Based on your code in your main method (the one that starts with public static void main(String[] args)) need to add

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Menu();
}
```

However as Issac said above I would highly recommend you take a look at a tutorial on creating GUI's as there are many more errors in your code past just not creating the GUI.

Comment: cheers ill try that im not very good at this im still in college and at my wits end with this program at the moment thank you for the help :)

Comment: just thought you it worked thank you so much you dont realise how much youve helped me stuck here for days haha :D

Comment: @aero123 If it helped perhaps accept as your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all the main method is the code that gets run when you run the program. If there is nothing in your main method, nothing is going to happen. Secondly, you have nothing that creates a GUI. I suggest you look into JPanel. You should probably do some kind of tutorial on Youtube if you're trying to make a GUI. I dont really know the requirements of your program or what youre trying to do at all so I cant really help much more than that without more information.

Comment: basically all im making is a simple window that has add a car then remove a car update a car and exit with a little picture on top its just a basic one im still learning this code